# IBM Worklight 6.2 - decode proguard obfuscated trace

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to use IBM Worklight Log and Analytics feature to upload and decode obfuscated crash reports (e.g. ProGuard or the iOS alternative) to the Worklight Server?

Comment: What are "obfuscated crash reports"?  ProGuard (and DexGuard) are code obfuscation tools.  The use of ProGuard does not obfuscate application outputs at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android ProGuard is currently not supported in Worklight (5.x - 6.2.0.x) applications, so in that respect this option is not available regardless. I am not familiar with an iOS equivalent to ProGuard.

AFAIK the [Worklight Operational Analytics platform](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_overview.html) does not provide the ability to *decode* uploaded logs. You can however [control what exactly you'd like to upload](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_data_capture.html).

Comment: By iOS alternative I meant symbolication and decoding with dSYMB files